# How to get recently inserted row index in Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to get the index of the most recently inserted record that was bound to a datalist?  My datalist is sorted, so my record is not the last one.  I am trying to highlight the record that just got inserted, so I need to know where it is in the datalist.

This is in ASP .NET C#.

edit:  I should probably rephrase my question.  After I insert a record, I "re-get" my records and rebind the datalist to update it with the inserted record.  Depending on what sort mode it is on, the newly added record can be anywhere in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I hope if this will work for you.

```
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
   <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

REF: [Autonumbering ASP.NET grid controls](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/AutonumberingASPNETGridControls.aspx)